# How can I include external code into unreal engine 4 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies, unreal-engine4

I've been coding an external C++ project in visual studio. For simplicity, let's say it is a calculator, which contains some `.h` files and the corresponding `.cpp` files.

I added the folder of the calculator headers into my Unreal Engine Visual Studio solution, at `VC++ Directories > Include Directories`. In the code of a component, I added my `.h`s and in `BeginPlay()`, I wrote something like:

```
Calculator c;
string sum = c.Sum(1, 2); //this method returns string 3
FString str(sum.c_str());
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *str);
```

Visual Studio has no problem, but after all, Unreal says `fatal error C1083: Unable to open include file` in my `.h` and nothing is even printed in the console. How can I correctly include my external headers and sources in order to use them into an Unreal Project?

Comment: You could create a plugin for that. Take a look at the implementation of [Dear ImGUI for Unreal](https://github.com/segross/UnrealImGui).

Comment: Although this is not the answer I'm searching for right now, it was the next thing I would try if I couldn't figure out how to import external code into Unreal's solution, so thanks for the link, I'll check it now.

Comment: It is the only one I could think of, because - at least afaik - the project files and solution are generated by Unreal, so editing them has no permanent result. I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do like this:
From Unreal Editor, I create an empty class.
Then I write my static method to be accessible from outside (public)

.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
        
/**
 *
 */
class PROJECT_NAME_API ClassName
{
public:
    static void YourFunctionName();
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "ClassName.h"
    
ClassName::YourFunctionName()
{
    //put your implementation here
}
```